# I am trying to simulate a network in Omnet. However I get an error saying "unresolved inclusion <csimplemodule.h>? How should I resolve this?

Tags: c++, simulation, ini, omnet++

In my code

```
include "csimplemodule.h"
```

The IDE indicates "unresolved inclusion csimplemodule.h";
I tried adding the path into GNU/C++ compiler. Still I am not able to solve the problem. Any help how to resolve this?

The error looks like this:
[image]

I did this to resolve. But it doesn't help:
[image]

Comment: Can you show us how you tried adding the path into gcc? The actual gcc line would be great.

Comment: @KompjoeFriek please see the edited post how I tried doing..

Answer (score 3):

1. There is no need to direct reference to `csimplemodule.h` because `omnetpp.h` includes all necessary header files.
2. Your class `Node` **has to inherit** from `cSimpleModule`.
3. `activity()` does not have arguments.

So your header file should look like:

```
#include <omnetpp.h>
using namespace omnetpp;

class Node : public cSimpleModule {
  private:
    int no_sent;
    int no_rcvd;
    double time_interval;
  protected:
    virtual void initialize();
    virtual void activity();
    virtual void finish();
};
```

A clue: you should consider using `handleMessage()` instead of `activity()`, look at cons and pros of both methods in [OMNeT++ Simulation Manual](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:simple-modules:activity).